# Reading old messages from the queue using Informatica Intelligent Cloud Services

Tags: queue, azure-servicebus-topics, informatica-cloud

I have created a two-process(for ex:- process A, process B). and I have TestQueue, TestTopic.

- **Process A** is to push the messages into the TestQueue.
- **Process B** is to read messages from the TestQueue and send it to TestTopic. This is an event-based process which means whenever a message is entered into the TestQueue then this process is triggered, reads the messages from the TestQueue and pushes it in TestTopic.

**Problem statement:**

- 1st I will disable the process B and pushes the message in TestQueue (by using process A) for example, the message is *TEST1*. Now I will enable the process B and again pushes the message in TestQueue for example, the message is *TEST2*.
- But the process B is able to read only the latest data which is *TEST2* and it is unable to load the old data which is *TEST1*(pushed to testQueue by disabling process B). I want both the messages should be read and pushed to TestTopic.

Does anyone has any idea on how to proceed further?

Note: these queues, topics are created in Azure Service bus and I am using AMQP connection to access them and created all these steps in Cloud Application Integration (Informatica Intelligent Cloud Services).

**Design of Process B**

[image: Design of Process B]

**Process B start properties**
[image: Process B start properties]
process B is an event whenever a message is loaded into testQueue then this process will automatically be triggered

**Assignment step image**
[image: Assignment step image]

the formula in Any is

```
    util:parseJSON(util:toJSON(
<AMQPMessage>
<body>
{
<PO-AMQP>
<Id>{$input.event[1]/body/body/PO-AMQP/Id/text()}</Id>
<Name>{$input.event[1]/body/body/PO-AMQP/Name/text()}</Name>
</PO-AMQP>
}
</body>
</AMQPMessage>))
```

**Service step assignment image**
[image: Service step assignment image]

Comment: You should be able to read more than 1 message at a time from a queue.

Comment: @GauravMantri that's the issue 2nd process is reading only 1 message because I have created it using event

Comment: How is your Process B invoked? Is it implemented as an Azure Function? Can you edit your question and share some code?

Comment: @GauravMantri I have edited the question. My problem is when process B is diabled and messages are pushed into the testQueue(done using process A) then the messages should wait in that testQueue only because no process is reading from it for example test2, test3, test4 these are the messages I have pushed into testQueue. Now I will enable process B and push test5 into testQueue. The process B is reading the only test5 and not reading the test2, test3, test4